# Core data - Delete Rule problem

Tags: iphone, core-data, has-many, cascading-deletes

I have a strange issue with delete rules in coredata. My data model is not so complicated. I detail here only relationships between elements :

```
A
----------
has_many B (optional, delete rule : Cascade)
has_many C (optional, delete rule : Cascade)

B
----------
has C (optional, delete rule : Cascade)
inv_A (delete rule : Nullify)

C
----------
has B (optional, delete rule : Nullify)
inv_A (delete rule : Nullify)
```

When I delete B, related C is not deleted. It is like cascade delete rule does not work...

Do you have an hint on what i am doing wrong ?

Thanks for your help

### EDIT

It was just a refetch issue. Stupid question... Never forget to :
A) Refetch data in base after having saved
B) Reload table with that new fetch result (or use a NSFetechedResultController)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delete rule always applies to the deletion of the *other* entity. So when you delete a `C` object, the `has C` relationship will make sure the  `B` is removed as well. The other way around, however, the `has B` relationship is only set to nullify so that’s what it does.

To clarify the situation, think about it this way: if you only had one relationship, say B references C, meaning B has a field for an object of type C. The only sensible thing for a delete rule to mean is solving the question of what should be done with said field if the object *it points to* should be deleted.

Comment: Strange… I just saw your edit: Are you sure your question correctly resembles your data model? If so, your `C` object should (as I explained) only be nullified, not deleted when the related B is removed…

Comment: Nice clarifying situation. That's a great way to think about it!